# Twitter images don't load on one device

Tags: macos, network, twitter

Periodically on my Mac, images and videos from Twitter fail to load, consistently for a few hours or days at a time. I get this or something like it in Safari, Twitter's app, and third party Twitter apps.

[image: Twitter post with missing image]

Some relevant-seeming details:

- Other devices on the same wifi network don't have this problem, it's just the one Mac.
- Aside from this, networking seems fine on the Mac. Only Twitter images and videos are affected.
- The Mac doesn't have any of its own firewalls, proxy configs, or anything special about its network setup.
- I'm currently on macOS 12.3.1 but this isn't a new problem.

Where can I look to try and find what's causing this?

Comment: I have a feeling iCloud Private Relay is going to trigger more API limits and recaptchas for us, but since this isn’t a new problem, I hate to suggest that.

Comment: I didn't think to mention it, but I don't use iCloud private relay.